# Convert data frame column to named list

Tags: r

Given a data frame

```
data <- data.frame(name = LETTERS[1:4],
                  value = 1:4)

> data
  name value
1    A     1
2    B     2
3    C     3
4    D     4
```

which *might* has row names

```
rownames(data) <- LETTERS[1:4]

> data
  name value
A    A     1
B    B     2
C    C     3
D    D     4
```

How can I convert a column to a **named** list, like

```
mylist <- list(A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4)

> mylist
$A
[1] 1

$B
[1] 2

$C
[1] 3

$D
[1] 4
```

---

What I have tried:

```
> data$value |> as.list()
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] 4
```

and also

```
> data |> select(value) |> as.list()
$value
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

---

Comment: What's wrong with `setNames(as.list(data$value), data$name)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose my comment is technically an answer. Using base R, you can use [`as.list()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/list), and then [`setNames()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/setNames.html):

```r
setNames(as.list(data$value), data$name)
# $A
# [1] 1

# $B
# [1] 2

# $C
# [1] 3

# $D
# [1] 4
```

It doesn't actually matter which order you call them in - you can set the names on the vector and convert to a list if you prefer.

Alternatively, if you prefer a `tidyverse` solution, [`dplyr::pull()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pull.html) used on two columns will give you a named vector, which you can convert to a list:

```r
data  |>
    dplyr::pull(value, name)  |>
    as.list()

# $A
# [1] 1

# $B
# [1] 2

# $C
# [1] 3

# $D
# [1] 4
```

For completeness, if you're using `data.table`, you could do:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[, setNames(value, name)]  |> as.list()
```

But I would probably just do this the base R way.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I came up with this solution simultaneously as [@SamR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12545041/samr) posted theirs.

---

Using `deframe` and `as.list` works:

```
> data |> dplyr::select(name, value) |> tibble::deframe() |> as.list()
$A
[1] 1

$B
[1] 2

$C
[1] 3

$D
[1] 4
```

Comment: You might want to specify that `deframe` is a function from the `tibble` package is not a base R function.